# How to calculate number of checkboxs'Id in a table via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna get the total number of the checkbox in a html.

request:
(1) By Javascript
(2) all my checkbox id is "id=idCheckBox", 
(3) each checkbox name is reserved for back-end using. not for javascript. 
(4) The naming for each checkbox's name is like checkbox_1, checkbox_2,... where the number indicate the serial number of a checkbox.

The Table Html

```
<table class="form_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="750px" id="idRoutineListTable">   
<tr>
   <td style="align:center;" class="routineListCell">
   <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_1' id='idCheckBox'></input>
   <!-- It may many checkbox here.-->
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My JS code, the function is to check any checkbox is selected before deletion. if no checkbox is selected, it pops up warning.

```
function beforeDelete()  /*{{{*/ 
{
    var checked=0;
    var checkboxAll=document.all["idCheckBox"];
    //the error is here, when there is only one checkbox, I cannot get length value, 
    //coz checkboxAll is not recognized as an array. However, if there are more than  
    //two checkboxes, the function works.
    alert (checkboxAll.length);    
    for(var i=0;i<checkboxAll.length;i++) {
        if (checkboxAll[i].checked==true) {
            checked++;
        }
    }
    if(checked==0) {
        alert('Please select the item you will delete');
        return false;
    } 
}  /*}}}*
```

The problem has indicate in the above code. 
Any idea to solve this?

Comment: Sidenote: You shouldn't use an id more than once....

Comment: Hi Yoshi, sorry, I cannot get you.

Comment: [7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) - *id*: 
`This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.`

Comment: Okay, I don't know about the rule. anyway, if I assigned many times for checkboxes (for my case), any problem will cause?

Answer (score 2):

here is a full working sample using jQuery:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function beforeDelete() {
        if ($("input:checked").length == 0) {
            alert('Please select the item you will delete');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>


<form onsubmit="return beforeDelete()">
    <table class="form_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="750px" id="idRoutineListTable">   
    <tr>
       <td style="align:center;" class="routineListCell">
       <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_1' id='idCheckBox'></input>
       <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_2' id='idCheckBox'></input>
       <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_3' id='idCheckBox'></input>
       <!-- It may many checkbox here.-->
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table>   
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, dknaack, I am quite new on web. I am C++ programmer...just temporarily doing web. I have zero knowledge on JQuery.

Comment: Hi dknaack, thanks for your attentions. learn new thing from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function beforeDelete()  {
    var checkboxAll=document.getElementsByTagName("input");   
    for(var i=0;i<checkboxAll.length;i++) {
        var input = checkboxAll[i];
        if (input.type == "checkbox" && input.checked==true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    alert('Please select the item you will delete');
    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first decision:
You may use **checkboxAll.length** as a condition to check if there is only one checkbox in your markup.

```
if(checkboxAll.length == undefined)
```

If not, you may use your code with loop, if it is only one checkbox - check only one.

The second decision:
To use getElementsByTag that will return you an array. In this case you need to filter this array with the given id

[Demo for both decisions here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fedor/vCekp/)

Comment: Hi Fedor Skrynnikov, yes, you're right. Just know I checked the type of the checkboxAll,  (code: checkboxAll instanceof Array), but I found it's not an array actually.  so what's kind of type of the checkboxAll?

Comment: I put a fiddle that you may check